# Interface lister

Tags: java, android, interface

I have an interface MyListner

```
public interface MyListner{
    public void onOperationComplete();
}
```

I have two Activity SignIn and SignUp which implements MyListner

```
public class SignIn extends Activity implements MyListner{
      @Override
      public void onOperationComplete(){
           Log.e("SignIn","Operation Complete");
      }
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.main);
           Operation.doOperation();
      }
}

public class SignUp extends Activity  implements MyListner{
      @Override    
      public void onOperationComplete(){    
           Log.e("SignUp","Operation Complete");
      }

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.main);    
          Operation.doOperation();

     }
 }
```

Inside onCreate() of both Activity i am calling a static function doOperation() inside the class Operation for doing some operation by Operation.doOperation().

```
public class Operation{
    publis static void doOperation(){
       ...........
       ...........
       ...........
       //here i want a callback to interface funtion onOperationComplete()
   }
}
```

My requirement is that i want to get a callback to the function onOperationComplete() inside all the class which implements MyListner

Answer (score 3):

make your doOperation like this:

```
public class Operation{
     publis static void doOperation(MyListener  callBack){
     ...........
      ...........
     ...........
     //here i want a callback to interface funtion onOperationComplete()
        callBack.onOperationComplete();
  }

}
```

In Your Activity:

```
public class SignIn extends Activity implements MyListner{
      @Override
      public void onOperationComplete(){
           Log.e("SignIn","Operation Complete");
      }
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.main);
           Operation.doOperation(this);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look for Observer pattern

You can make your Operation class singleton

Add an attribute of "Collection listeners" inside Operation class

Add a public method called "addListener(MyListener)" which stores the passed parameter into the "listeners" attribute

Inside onCreate() of the Activity, call

```
Operation.getInstance().addListener(this);
```

When you want to perform the operation, call

```
for(MyListener listener : listeners){
    listener.onOperationComplete();
}
```